# Two newly created objects seem to refer to the same address

Tags: java

I'm programming in Java for only a few months so I'm not that experienced with Java (some tricks and the basic things I should know though).

I got a problem which may be obvious but I don't see it.

```
public class SomeClass {
   private final int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

   private LabelText AText = new LabelText('A', numbers);
   private LabelText BText = new LabelText('B', numbers);

   public void foo() {
       AText.numbers[6] = -1;
       BText.numbers[3] = -1;
       if (BText.numbers[6] == -1) System.out.println("Wtf?");
   }
}
```

This is an extract from my code.

How can this be true? These are two separate objects. I don't get it.

The foo method is called directly in my main method (for test purposes).

If you need the constructor of LabelText, here it is:

```
public class LabelText {

   private final char letter;
   public int[] numbers;

   public LabelText(char letter, int[] numbers) {
       this.letter = letter;
       this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question: deep copy vs shallow copy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you are passing a *reference* to `numbers` without making a copy, so both objects end up pointing to *the same* `int[]` *instance*. While there are two *different* outer objects, the inner object that they both point to is *the same object*, hence you can change that inner object by dereferencing either of `AText.numbers` and `BText.numbers`, and the change will be visible in both of the outer objects when accessing their `numbers` fields.

You can check that `AText == BText` will return `false`, but `AText.numbers == BText.numbers` will return `true`. And `this.numbers == AText.numbers` will also return `true`.

Like try this same code but with this constructor:

```
public LabelText(char letter, int[] numbers) {
   this.letter = letter;
   this.numbers = numbers.clone(); // so it will always be unique array here
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your solid contribution to that immutable class discussion ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Object Refreneces in Java:**

In Java programming language there are two data types: primitive and reference.

- Primitives: char, byte, short, int, long, float and double
- Reference: All objects in Java and *arrays*.

Example Java objects:

- In Java programming language there are classes like `String`,
  `Exception`, `Integer` and `File`. Objects are created using such
  classes. In addition, one can create custom classes and objects -
  like, a `Person` or `LabelText`.

A Java object is created as follows. If `Person` is a class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setAge(int i) {
        age = i;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Consider the code:

```
Person personA = new Person("A", 32);
```

In the above statement, the `Person` is a class, `personA` is a variable and `new Person(..)` creates an object of type `Person`. The `=` assigns the newly created `Person` object to the variable `personA`. The `personA` is a variable of reference type and this points or references to the newly created `Person` object.

The `Person` class has the attributes (or properties) `name` and `age`. These represent the *state* of the object. In general, the state differentiates between objects.

How does this reference type behave? See this example code:

```
public class TestingReferences {
    public void foo() {
        Person a = new Person("A", 32); // 1
        Person b = new Person("B", 28); // 2
        Person c = a; // 3
        a.setName("X"); // 4
        System.out.println("Are the names of a and c equal? " +
                a.getName().equals(c.getName())); // 5
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TestingReferences app = new TestingReferences();
        app.foo();
    }
}
```

In the above example code note the output printed in the method `foo()` - both the persons *a* and *c* have the same name *X*. How does this happen?

1: `Person a = new Person("A", 32);` A new person object is created and assigned to variable `a`.

2: `Person b = new Person("B", 28);` A new person object is created and assigned to variable `b`.

3: `Person c = a;` A person variable `c` is created -and- it is assigned the reference variable `a`. At this stage, both the reference variables `a` and `c` are pointing or referencing to the same person object (see picture below).

4: `a.setName("X");` The person object `a`'s `name` is changed from "A" to "X".

5: `System.out.println("Are the names of a and c equal? " + a.getName().equals(c.getName()));` This prints `true`!

Since the both the reference variables `a` and `c` are pointing to the same object, any changes to the state of the object is seen by both the references.

If the statement is added to `foo`: `c.setAge(44);`, The `age` for both the persons `a` and `c` are set to 44.

[image]

The above example demonstrates how the object references behave in Java programming language. The same is applied to the question in this post.

**From the Post's Question:**

Note that arrays, both arrays of primitives (like `int[]`) and arrays of objects (`Person[]`), are always objects.

1: `private final int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`

2: `private LabelText AText = new LabelText('A', numbers);`

3: `private LabelText BText = new LabelText('B', numbers);`

There are three objects and reference variables in the above three statements. Note the `numbers` object reference is assigned to the state of the `AText` and `BText`. All these three references of the `numbers` array are pointing to the same array object created on *line 1*. Now, in the method `foo()`:

```
AText.numbers[6] = -1;
BText.numbers[3] = -1;
(BText.numbers[6] == -1) ... returns true -and- 
(AText.numbers[3] == -1) ... also, returns true.
```

Add this statement to method `foo`: `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers));`
This prints: `[0, 1, 2, -1, 4, 5, -1, 7, 8, 9]`. Note the array values in positions *3* and *6*.

Comment: @snr Thanks for approving my answer post. It is (almost) always difficult for Java newbie's to understand the concepts of object-oriented programming - object creation and references. I had such questions when I started, hence the detailed example.

Comment: So if I would create another array (e.g. named `number2`) and pass this to the constructor of `BText`, then I would have two seperated arrays where I can change the values independent from the other one, right?

Comment: @DarkBarbarian yes