# Referencing and updating an Object in multiple locations

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

I am trying to create a Java program that saves information for students and parents(both custom classes) and generates a daily roll sheet from those lists. I am trying to add payments/charges into it and have reached a problem. In my main program I have an ArrayList for Students and another for Parents. Students currently have a field that is an ArrayList of their parents and parents the same for their children. When I update the information it is either updating only in my main parent list or in the parent list of one individual student, not both. What is the best method of creating a list of objects and updating them from multiple locations/classes?

Here is some of my Student class. I can add any other parts of my code that would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Student extends Person implements Serializable
{
private ArrayList<String> mAllergies;
private ArrayList<Calendar> mDates;
private ArrayList<Parent> mParents;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, ArrayList<String> allergies, ArrayList<Calendar> dates)
{
    mFirstName = firstName;
    mLastName = lastName;
    mAllergies = allergies;
    mDates = dates;
    mParents = new ArrayList<>();
    mMoneyOwed = 0;
    setFullName();
}

public ArrayList<Parent> getParents()
{
    return mParents;
}

public void setParents(ArrayList<Parent> parents)
{
    mParents = parents;
}

public String listParents()
{
    String output = "";
    for (Parent p : mParents)
        output += p.getFullName() + ", ";
    if (output.length() > 1)
        output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 2);
    else
        output += "None on file";
    return output;
}

public void addParent(Parent parent)
{
    mParents.add(parent);
    parent.getChildren().add(this);
}
```

Comment: Please share some code, it would be easier to understand

Comment: Thank you, I added part of my Student class, I was uncertain what else would be helpful but am happy to add any other sections of code.

Comment: *"When I update the information it is either updating only in my main parent list or in the parent list of one individual student, not both. What is the best method of creating a list of objects and updating them from multiple locations/classes?"* ... this is not clearly defining the problem that you are having.  Can you provide a concrete example of an update that is not performing as you are expecting?

Comment: @scottb when I update the mMoneyOwed variable for a student it updates the mMoneyOwed for every Parent object in their parent list. It does not update the mMoneyOwed for the 'same' parent object contained in the parent list on my main file. I am hoping to use the same parent object in both places so the fields always match

Comment: The phrase "It does not update ... on my main file" is confusing because the word file has no concrete meaning in this context.  The example code you present performs no file access.   I *think* that the problem you are having relates to object access in general.  Just because `A` has a reference to `B` does not mean than `B` knows anything about `A`.  In this case `B` will not respond to any changes to `A`.  If you need `B` to respond to changes made in `A`, then event-driven mechanisms could be used by registering `B` as an Observer of one or more fields of `A`.

Comment: @HannahMishow Both lists should refer to the same parent objects, so a modified property from a list should be visible also from all other lists. Unless you are making hard copies instead of reusing the same objects. Do you have a practical example? Maybe a [mcve] showing the problem?

Comment: @HannahMishow You may want to share the code where you are updating the student or/and its parent. It is difficult to understand (and respond with) what is happening based on the code or comments you have posted so far.

Comment: This post with some info about Object Refreneces in Java may be of help : [Two newly created objects seem to refer to the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717223/two-newly-created-objects-seem-to-refer-to-the-same-address).