# How program passes values to method ranking()

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

**Hi all,**
I would like to ask you for help to understand logic of this program specially some parts that I am probably stack in.

1.Method `ranking()`. It doesn´t accept any parametr but returns result from parametrs "won" and "tied". OK. But when we call this method like this

```
System.out.println(adelaideCrows.getName()+": result: 
         "+**adelaideCrows.ranking()**);
```

how the program knows values of "won" and "tied" for this adealideCrows team? I know that OOP is about passing objects respective references to objects. So does it work so that when we firstly call method `adelaideCrows.matchResult(ohioFotlball, 1,0);` then adelaideCrows is the reference to method matchResult passing there parametres in brackets and then they are stored in memory under reference of adelaideCrows? so when we next call the same method with another reference `melbournSoccer.matchResult(newyorkSoccer,6,4);` then parametres "won" and "tied" have their own values passed in brackets under reference melbournSoccer? So after calling method ranking() with reference e.g. adelaideCrows program knows that under this reference there are already stored values of parametres "won" and "tied" and method then returns correct values. Right?

2.And also here `System.out.println(melbournSoccer.compareTo(newyorkSoccer));` Does the logic is the same? melbournSoccer reference is connected in method `public int compareTo(Team<T> team)` to `this.ranking()` but reference newyorkSoccer is connected to `team.ranking()`? So calling `this.ranking()` invokes values stored in memory of reference melbournSoccer and so on?

Thank A LOT.

Here is the code for Main class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SoccerPlayer soccerPlayer = new SoccerPlayer("joe");
        BaseballPlayer baseballPlayer = new BaseballPlayer("pat");
        FootballPlayer footballPlayer = new FootballPlayer("backham");


         Team<FootballPlayer> adelaideCrows = new Team<>("Adelaide Crows 
         footbal");
         Team<SoccerPlayer> melbournSoccer = new Team<>("Melbourn soccer");
         Team<BaseballPlayer> jerseeBaseball = new Team<>("Jersee 
         Baseball");


         melbournSoccer.addPlayer(soccerPlayer);
         jerseeBaseball.addPlayer(baseballPlayer);

         adelaideCrows.matchResult(ohioFotlball, 1,0);
         melbournSoccer.matchResult(newyorkSoccer,6,4);

         System.out.println("Ranking...");
         System.out.println(adelaideCrows.getName()+": result: 
         "+adelaideCrows.ranking());
         System.out.println(melbournSoccer.getName()+": result: 
         "+melbournSoccer.ranking());
         System.out.println(jerseeBaseball.getName()+": result: 
         "+jerseeBaseball.ranking());


         System.out.println(melbournSoccer.compareTo(newyorkSoccer)); 
         System.out.println(adelaideCrows.compareTo(ohioFotlball));
```

---

Player class here from which another three classes FotballPlayer, SoccerrPlayer and BaseballPlayer inherits.

```
public abstract class Player{
    private String name;

    public Player(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

---

And here is Team class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team<T extends Player> implements Comparable<Team<T>>{
    private String name;
    int played = 0;
    int lost = 0;
    int won = 0;
    int tied = 0;

    private ArrayList<T> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public Team(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean addPlayer(T player){    
        if(members.contains(player)){
            System.out.println(player.getName()+" is already on this 
   team.");
            return false;
        }else{
            members.add(player);
            System.out.println(player.getName()+" has been added to team 
  "+this.name);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int numPlayers(){
        return this.members.size();

    }

    public void matchResult(Team<T> oponent, int ourScore, int theirScore){
        if(ourScore > theirScore){
            won++;
        }else if(ourScore == theirScore){
            tied++;
        }else{
            lost++;
        }
        played++;
        if(oponent != null){
            oponent.matchResult(null, theirScore, ourScore);
        }
    }

    public int ranking(){
        return (won * 2) + tied;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Team<T> team){
       if(this.ranking() > team.ranking()){
           return -1;
       } else if(this.ranking() < team.ranking()){
               return 1;
       }
            else{
                   return 0;
               }

       }



}
```

Comment: *specially some parts that I am probably stack in.* Don't get stack! Use a debagger!

Comment: This forum is about to ask and not everybody is advanced or specialist so thanks for your respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some clarifications to the questions.

**Question 1**:

> Method `ranking()`. It doesn´t accept any parametr but returns result
>   from parametrs "won" and "tied". OK. But when we call this method like
>   this:

```
System.out.println(adelaideCrows.getName() + ": result: " + **adelaideCrows.ranking()**);
```

> how the program knows values of "won" and "tied" for this
>   `adealideCrows` team? ...

**Answer 1**:

Consider this statement in the `Main` class: `adelaideCrows.matchResult(ohioFotlball, 1, 0);`. When this statement executes:

- The `adelaideCrows` object gets affected. In the `matchResult` method the
  instance variables `won` and `tied` are changed based on the method input
  parameters (`1` and `0`, in this case).
- When the statement `adelaideCrows.ranking()` is executed, the `ranking()` method uses the `adelaideCrows`'s object instance variables `won` and `tied` (which were set earlier) to calculate the ranking (`(won * 2) + tied`) and return the value.

**NOTES**: See this article (my answer) on StackOverflow to get an idea about a Java class, an object, a reference, and class's attributes and behavior: [Object References in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717223/two-newly-created-objects-seem-to-refer-to-the-same-address/51718625#51718625).

**Question 2**:

> And also here
>   `System.out.println(melbournSoccer.compareTo(newyorkSoccer));` Does the
>   logic is the same? `melbournSoccer` reference is connected in method
>   `public int compareTo(Team<T> team)` to `this.ranking()` but reference
>   `newyorkSoccer` is connected to `team.ranking()`? So calling
>   `this.ranking()` invokes values stored in memory of reference
>   `melbournSoccer` and so on?

**Answer 2**:

Consider the statement: `System.out.println(melbournSoccer.compareTo(newyorkSoccer));`

Q). `melbournSoccer` reference is connected in method `public int compareTo(Team<T> team) to this.ranking()`

A). The keyword `this` refers to the current object - here it is `melbournSoccer`. `this.ranking` method gets the ranking for the `melbournSoccer`.

Q). Reference `newyorkSoccer` is connected to `team.ranking()`?

A). The method parameter `compareTo()` takes a `Team` as input - here it is a `newyorkSoccer` team object.

Q). So calling `this.ranking()` invokes values stored in memory of reference `melbournSoccer` and so on?

A). YES.

**NOTES**: Here is a link to Oracle's Java tutorials topic [Using the **this** Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score -1):

I try to answer your first question: The variables „won“ and „tied“ are instance variables. That means every time you create an object of your team class, the object gets its own „won“ and „tied“ variable to save data in it. You can access them with the name of the unique object (in your case the team name as example „adelaideCrows.won“ without the quotes). To answer the question about the „matchResult“ function: The function is related to your object again because you are not using „static“ declaration in front of the method name. So without static every instance of your class gets their own method so if you are passing parameters to that function they are passed into the objects function. If you want to save them you have to create a class variable (which is made with „static int“ as example) or a instance variable in order to save the data as long as the object exists, otherwise the data will get passed to the function and will be lost after the function execution is finished.

Comment: Hi @Brogroswav also wanna thank you for your answer. Have a very nice day.