# Why does the button object behave differently depending on where it is declared

Tags: java, android, object, reference

I am writing a Android App in Java (with Codename One). I am into Java for about 3 years (Swing, FX, after a year of Python), but not a professional programmer. So, for the pros around, kindly bear with me.

**Here is my issue:** I have noted that a project can run quite differently, depending on if a var is initiated inside a for-loop or at the beginning of a class.

Here is some code:

In the **first scenario**, a button is instantiated inside the for-loop, either  calling the button, or adding it via a list. When running the project, the results are identical :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        Button button = new Button("test"); // OR
        Button button = new Button(list.get(i));
        form.add(button);
 };
```

In the **second scenario**, the button is instantiated outside the for-loop. In this scenario, the result is different when I use an ArrayList, or a button.

```
public class Test {

    private Button button;

    public void animation() {       

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            button = new Button("test");        // OR
            button = new Button(list.get(i));
            form.add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a timer in the project, and when I add a button with the second approach, the components show up in an uncoordinated manner, what does not occur when I use the fist approach.

I have solved the programming part, but, independently of the immediate consequences on the project, why is it that in Java it can matter at which point, inside or outside a for-loop, you instantiated a variable? And why does it matter if I use an ArrayList or not?

To me, it doesn't make sense. Is this unexpected java behavior, or is there something going on under the hood, that I don't know of?

Anybody can explain?

Comment: In your second snippt of code, you have only one `Button` reference, even you add it for multiple times, they are pointing the the same instance.

Comment: The issue is to do with understanding some basic concepts in Java and object-oriented programming: What is (1) instance variable, (2) local or method variable (3) reference variable and its behavior. What happens when a reference variable is assigned an object and is re-assigned with another object?

Comment: Nitpick: "*In the second scenario, the button is instantiated outside the for-loop.*" that is not what your code shows. *Instantiate* means creating instance (*object* of class) and it is done via `new Button(...);` which in both cases happens inside loop. Also reference to that instance is *assigned* to `button` *variable*. Only thing in second scenario related to `button` which is outside of loop is *declaration* of that variable (which in this case is field).

Comment: In this case there should be no difference in the behavior of your two samples, unless `animation()` can be called concurrently from different threads -- then the assignment to the instance variable `button` will overwrite the value set by the other thread and might cause some odd behavior. Can you explain what 'show up in an uncoordinated manner' means, and what you mean by 'why does it matter if I use an ArrayList or not'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my issue: I have noted that a project can run quite
>   differently, depending on if a var is initiated inside a for-loop or
>   at the beginning of a class.

Some clarifications:

**Scenario 1:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        Button button = new Button("test"); // OR
        Button button = new Button(list.get(i));
        form.add(button);
 };
```

Consider the statement: `Button button = new Button("Press me");`

`new Button()` creates a new `Button` object and is assigned (the `=`) to the variable `button`. `button` is a reference variable of type `Button`. And, `button` refers or points to a memory location. Note the above code is within a method and also within a block (for-loop) - so `button` is a local or method variable.

For each iteration of the for loop a new `Button` object is created and the reference (memory location) is stored or added to the `form`. If the for loop runs 3 times there are three *different* `Button` objects and three references.

**Scenario 2:**

```
private Button button;
```

The above statement is declaring a `button` reference variable (of type Button). It is an *instance variable*; there is only one instance of it for an (one) object of the class it is declared in. This means, whenever an object of the class `Test` is created (for example, `Text test = new Test()`, or `new Test()`), there will be only one variable `button` and one location in the memory.

```
public void animation() {       

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        button = new Button("test");
        form.add(button);
```

The first time the code `button = new Button("test");` is run, in the for-loop, the instance variable `button` is assigned a new `Button` object (new Button("test")). This points to the memory location of the `button` variable. For the second iteration of the for-loop another new `Button` object is created and is assigned to the *same* button variable (memory location), etc.

So, the `button` instance variable's memory location is re-assigned again and again and that is the reason you see this "un-coordinted" behaviour.

**NOTES:**

See this post authored by me: [Object References in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717223/two-newly-created-objects-seem-to-refer-to-the-same-address/51718625#51718625).

Also, try to know what is a heap memory in Java.

Comment: ,many thanks for taking the time to elaborate this detailed and informative reply. Haven't thought about the thing with the memory. Very interesting, indeed. I love programming in java, even though I'm trying to get closer to other languages, like vala. But many times I feel like Plato: "I know that I know nothing". I will definitely keep up on my reading.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am knowing about "Vala" programming language for the first time - another OO programming language. I think Plato is little older...

Comment: Vala is Java-related. I imagined you would have heard about it. It's developed by, and used for, Gnome application. Don't know if it's worth the effort to delve into it. Also not sure that this place is ideal for this comment, but I'm a big Linux fan and thinking about developing application for Ubuntu. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/About

Comment: I had checked out the wiki earlier only. I learned Haskell little bit to understand functional programming - it is useful to learn functional style APIs (Streams and Functions) of Java 8. For, 2019 I am seriously learning JavaScript and I finding it interesting (only the language, not the web application aspects) and I am just about finishing an online course.

Comment: would you like to chat about programming and technical stuff outside this discussion forum?

Comment: Prasad, sorry for keeping you waiting. Busy times around here. I am also facing difficulties identifying a proper chat platform. Your name is not in the list of names in stack overflow chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=name . How can we go about chatting? I am no friend of facebook .. :-)

Comment: You can contact me at this email: googuser90 at gmail (d0t) com.